# How to implement zopfli for a better gzip compression?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, compression, gzip

[Google says](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57571982-93/google-compression-algorithm-zopfli-may-lead-to-faster-internet/) [Zopfli](https://code.google.com/p/zopfli/) gives a better gzip-functionality and it's compatible with all browsers (decompression is the same, compression takes a lot longer, but you get an additional 5-10% smaller static files footprint)

So, i know you can do this for gzip compression of static files:

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files"
 dynamicCompressionDisableCpuUsage="90"
 dynamicCompressionEnableCpuUsage="80"
maxDiskSpaceUsage="100" minFileSizeForComp="2700"
noCompressionForRange="true"
sendCacheHeaders="false"
staticCompressionDisableCpuUsage="100"
staticCompressionEnableCpuUsage="80"    >
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" dynamicCompressionLevel="4" 
          staticCompressionLevel="7" />
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/rss+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </staticTypes>

</httpCompression>
```

...

But how would you implement Zopfli instead of the standard GZip-library in web.config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zopfli compression is slow, so I would recommend compressing static files before uploading them, even better use a CDN and Zopfli for static files.

If you are using .net take a look at a library I recently published on github

https://github.com/echovoice/libzopfli-sharp

I derived the Stream class, usage is simple

```
using (MemoryStream compressStream = new MemoryStream())
using (ZopfliStream compressor = new ZopfliStream(compressStream, ZopfliFormat.ZOPFLI_FORMAT_DEFLATE))
{
    compressor.Write(uncompressed, 0, before);
    compressor.Close();
    compressed = compressStream.ToArray(); // here is the compressed data
}
```

This library is available on Nuget as libzopfli-sharp, https://www.nuget.org/packages/libzopfli-sharp

So it would be possible to use this class to create and register a filter for IIS, but that would be a bad idea and make website performance worse.

Comment: If registering an IIS filter gives us bad performance, does that mean we can't utilize zopfli to improve web application performance?

Comment: No, but zopfli should really be used on static content and cached for a long period of time. The CPU usage on the web application server isn't worth the cost.

Answer (score 6):

You can get [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/) for static compression, which is a parallel gzip replacement that includes zopfli compression at level 11.

zopfli would likely not be beneficial for dynamic compression, since it will take much longer to compress out that extra few percent of data than it would take to simply transmit that extra few percent of data.

zopfli is intended for those cases where something is compressed once and then sent or stored many times and decompressed many times.  Not for cases where something is compressed once and decompressed once.

Comment: I would say it depends, if you expect people on limited bandwith with severe caps such as cellphones, Africa or rural dialup infested America to acess your site. It might be worth it. It would be nice if browsers could indicate such link atributes to the server.

Comment: Also I might point out that pigz does nothing more than zopfli itself perhaps less since you say it only compresses at level 11 wearas zopfli has optoins at least... even thought it is a rather nice tool you wrote.

Comment: pigz uses zopfli in parallel on multiple cores, whereas the zopfli command-line tool does not.  Considering how slow zopfli is, this can be a significant benefit.

Comment: Yes, there may be outlier bandwidth cases where it would be worthwhile.  Hence the term "likely".

Comment: @MarkAdler "pigz uses zopfli in parallel on multiple cores". While using zopfli at level 11, how does pigz divide the input data to compress it parallely?

Comment: It simply breaks the input into blocks, by default 128k but user selectable, compresses each block with a 32K dictionary from the previous block (so as to not impact compression), and then combines the compressed data and writes it to the output.  The CRC calculations are also done for each block, with the CRCs combined to calculate the total CRC.

Comment: @MarkAdler as we know that zopfli uses LZ77 compression algoithm, which can not be perfectly parallelized because it may use a reference to a duplicated string occuring in a previous block, up to 32K input bytes before, so how pigz uses zopfli in parallel?

Comment: I explained that already.  Each thread gets the 128K of uncompressed data it is to compress and the 32K of uncompressed data that precedes it.

Answer (score 1):

This question was posed over a year ago, but a few things have changed, and this may benefit future landers on this page:

1. First, it's important to highlight that **zopfli creates gzip files**. So at the level of analysis implied in the web.config (or .htaccess), there wouldn't be any zopfli-awareness.
2. Because it is at least an order of magnitude slower than DEFLATE/typical gzipping, it's not in the running for on-the-fly compression, which is what IIS and Apache are doing. It's unlikely we'll ever see the zopfli algorithm implemented on a server for on-the-fly compression.
3. You can use zopfli in advance, to *pre-compress* your assets before deploying them on the server. One way you can now do this is via a node.js package: [node-zopfli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-zopfli).

And now Telerik has a [neat tool](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/14-07-02/maximize-compression-with-zopfli) that will tell you if your assets would benefit from zopfli, and by how much.

The zopfli source code library is [here.](https://code.google.com/p/zopfli/source/checkout)

[Pigz](https://github.com/madler/pigz) is one implementation, and Krzysztof Kowalczyk has [ported it to Windows](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/pigz-for-windows.html).

Comment: RE: "zopfli is not a gzip alternative." Sure it is. You can emit gzip, deflate, or zlib files.

Comment: @EricLaw I'm not sure what I meant by that statement – probably that it's not a different format, e.g. emitting .zop files or some such. You're right though – it is a gzip alternative. I'm going to delete that sentence. (In other news, I really wish it was easier to do pre-compression on servers – it's nuts that we gzip the same files over and over and over.)

Comment: Ah. `Zopfli.exe` is an alternative to `gzip.exe`; it can generate compatible output in the `gzip format`. As for "I really wish it was easier to do pre-compression on servers" -- it's pretty trivial on many servers; which are you using?

Comment: @EricLaw, I'm mostly looking at Caddy Server for my new personal/science site. Seems like a nice piece of work, easier to deploy than nginx. I'm also curious about h2o, but it seems risky since I don't see anyone using it (https://github.com/h2o/h2o). I like that he was using the SSE 4.2 string compare instructions to speed parsing – almost no one uses, or seems to know about, these and similar instructions that modern CPUs have. I'd appreciate any server recommendations you have, or thoughts on Caddy and h2o. I'll be on Vultr or DO, using Intel Clear Linux, CoreOS or Alpine. I have Azure too.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible yet! You should be able to precompress any files you have though manually.

Currently [zopfli is not a dll/library](http://code.google.com/p/zopfli/issues/detail?id=11) so you can't use it to dynamically compress things unless you were able to write a script to handle it but that would be outside the scope of your question.

I think it may be possible in the future once zopfli is converted to a library to either drop it in place of gzip.dll or write a wrapper to do so.